# PayPal: skip trial period

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have created a hosted PayPal button for monthly subscription and included its code on my website.

The subscription offers a free trial period of 1 week.
I would like to check if the user has already used their trial and is trying to subscribe again. And if so, how do I let PayPal know that it should not allow a trial period for that user?

The button's code looks something like this:

```html
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABCDEFGHIJKLM">
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Your email">
    <label for="plan-email">Your email</label>
    <input id="plan-email" type="email" name="os0" placeholder="joanne.doe@gmail.com" required maxlength="200">
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

It would be even better, if you know a way to use Subscription Plan (created in https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans) as an HTML form similar to the one above (pure HTML form, without using PayPal JavaScript SDK) instead of a Button (created in https://www.paypal.com/buttons/). I need to pass an extra option (user's email) to PayPal as well as whether to allow a trial period or not.